# Неправильная геолокация SEO

Tags: веб-программирование, seo, поиск, веб-сайт

У меня есть одностраничный сайт с генерацией `<title> <description> <keywords>` в зависимости от города пользователя. Проблема в том, что при запросе через Google и Яндексе мне выдается мой сайт с двумя разными городами. В Google это Анадырь, а в Яндексе это Москва. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Автоматическая геолокация не бывает точной. Делай на сайте уточнение/выбор пользователем нужного города. (это нужно делать не только по причине гео)

Comment: Этот функционал есть, проблема в том, что роботы заходят из разных мест и поэтому они индексируют в Анадыре (google), а Яндекс в Москве.